# VBA working code suddenly gives runtime error 91 - related to XMLHTTP

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, runtime

**EDIT:**
I have tested the response text and I found out the reason behind the error is that the request gets redirected to the "I'm not a robot" page due to high number of search requests sent by excel. Is there anything that can be done to prevent this from happening?

**Original:**
I have this code (found it online and modified it) that works fine when i execute it few times, it then creates

> Run-time error " 91 - Object Variable or with block variable not set"

Then after I wait for about an hour it works fine without me changing anything, then it creates the error again. and so on...

The code was originally to search Google for a list of strings and return how many results. I modified it to search for the exact string and just return if there are results or not.

Here is the code:

```
Sub SearchHits()

Dim url, name As String
Dim i, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object
Dim html As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

lastRow = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    Name = """" & Cells(i, 1).Value & """"
    url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & Name & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send

    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText

If html.getElementById("topstuff").innerText <> "" Then  '<-----Highlighted on error
    Cells(i, 9) = "–"
Else
    Cells(i, 9) = "Results Found"
End If
Next

End Sub
```

I'm not sure what is the reason, I have few guesses but am hoping someone over here could explain to me the reason and the work around. I work in research and everyday I search a lot of names and it would be very helpful if I can know which has results and which doesn't.

It would be even more amazing if someone can help with the code to return the exact number of searches (the one found at the bottom of the page).

Best Regards!

Comment: check response text XMLHTTP.ResponseText

Comment: @techie .. what should I check for?

Comment: @techie ,,, I checked the response text and I found out that my search request is taken as a bot and the respnose text is the reCAPTCHA page ... any ideas ?